# Tasks queue up, nothing happens on retry (no log)

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I noticed that over 1,000 tasks queued up in Google App Engine's task queue. When I hit "Run Now" nothing seems to happen, no error in the log entry, etc. I double checked everything, but everything seems fine. The only suspicious thing to me was under the "Previous Run" tab in the task queue console, it showed "Last http response code: 404". Despite the 404, the URL seems fine, I can call it in a browser. Also, tasks just like those also run as expected. Without a log, I do not know what else to check.

Some tasks may have failed before, but after a fix, that error should be gone.

I'm using Java App Engine SDK 1.7.0 and a custom queue like this:

```
<queue>
    <name>data-import</name>
    <rate>1/s</rate>
    <bucket-size>3</bucket-size>
    <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
</queue>
```

So, any clues what's going on? Or what else to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you still experiencing the problem?  Are you using Master/Slave or High Replication?

You can report a bug and provide your application id.

Comment: Meanwhile I purged the queue, and right now it seems fine. Thanks.