# 404 Instance Unavailable when running a Task Queue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm using Java SDK 1.7.5, **HRD** datastore with the following task queue setup:

```xml
<queue>
  <name>surveyAssembly</name>
  <rate>5/s</rate>
  <bucket-size>20</bucket-size>
  <max-concurrent-requests>10</max-concurrent-requests>
</queue>
```

[image: GAE console]

I'm getting a HTTP 404 when triggering the task. No errors in the logs just failing silently.

It seems a similar issue to this one [Tasks queue up, nothing happens on retry (no log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734606/tasks-queue-up-nothing-happens-on-retry-no-log) but no luck after purging the queue.

Any ideas on how to diagnose the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same error.  After debug I found that I forget to deploy back-end version from eclipse. So You have to confirm that both backend and frontend has same updated code.

Try this code 
//backends.xml

```
<backends>
 <backend name="mailback">
 </backend>
</backends>
```

// Queue code

```
Queue surveyAssemblyQueue = QueueFactory.getQueue("surveyAssembly");
surveyAssemblyQueue.add(withUrl("/taskloop")param("type", type).header("Host",BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("mailback", 0)));
```

Note:  Instant Id should be "0" because I have created only 1 backend instant.