# Is 'Run Now' button broken on Google App Engine Task Queue?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My task on Google App Engine's Task Queue didn't retry after failure the way it usually does.  So I clicked the 'Run Now' button instead.  Google App Engine seems that it simply isn't responding.  Someone else had this problem a while ago ([Tasks queue up, nothing happens on retry (no log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734606/tasks-queue-up-nothing-happens-on-retry-no-log)) and they purged their Task Queue to fix the problem.  I can do that but is there something else I can try first?

Here are some things I checked:

1] Logs - nothing appears in the log after I press 'Run Now'.

2] Too many retries? - I don't think it's exceeded the number of retries because the Task Queue interface doesn't indicate that any retries have occurred.

3] Quota exceeded? - No, I only used 7% of my daily budget when the error occurred and the quota page doesn't indicate any problem.

4] "Previous Run" tab in the task queue console - A "Previous Run" tab was mentioned in [Tasks queue up, nothing happens on retry (no log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734606/tasks-queue-up-nothing-happens-on-retry-no-log) but that doesn't seem to exist anymore.

5] New vs. Old admin interface - For all the admin console screens mentioned above, I checked both the new (console.developers.google.com) and the old (appengine.google.com) interfaces.

6] Clues in the log? - Looking at the log where my task failed, I don't see any clue as to why Task Queue wouldn't retry.  The task failed because it was calling another server and that threw a `java.net.SocketExceptionSocket operation timed out: The API call remote_socket.Receive() took too long to respond and was cancelled.`.  It's something a simple retry should be able to fix.  But the retry is not happening.

So, any clues what's going on? Or what else to check?

Comment: Do you have more than one module? Or are you using a non-default version to test with?

Comment: Hi @Greg, yes I'm using 2 modules and passing the task from one to the other over the default task queue.

Comment: I have a theory: maybe the task is still running!  The task I'm running is multi-threaded and it's one of the threads that threw the exception.  Maybe the main thread is still sitting there waiting and the task won't get retried until it expires after 24 hours (since I'm using Basic Scaling, not Automatic Scaling). I'm just not sure why I'm given a 'Run Now' button if the task is already running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I suspected in my comment to my original post, the task was actually still running. Since it was a multi-threaded task, it was really a spawned thread that had gotten the `java.net.SocketExceptionSocket` exception and it was the main thread that was just stuck endlessly waiting for the child thread to finish.

After 24 hours, Google App Engine canceled the task: `com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (eac8786ce44a6a02) started at 2014/12/10 00:57:07.139 UTC and was still executing at 2014/12/11 00:56:56.850 UTC`.

Once Google App Engine canceled the task, it then began to retry the task so I'm back in business.